# Website pulling in content from other website, but the URL is the same. Possible redirection?

Tags: redirection, url

I am facing a bit of a unique situation here.

So I have a website say `http://www.example1.com` Now, sometimes, when I browse to that site, I am redirected to `http://www.example2.com`, but the url in the address bar is still `http://www.example1.com`

Why is this redirection happening? Does anyone has any idea? Don't know what is stuffing it up?! I had created this website some time ago - it is mainly built in Flash.

My question mainly is - what would enforce a site to pull in contents of another site without changing the URL in the browser. Could it be IIS configuration or something else? I couldn't notice anything dodgy in the configuration, but if there is something else I need to check, please let me know! IFrame is ***not*** being used.

This is happening on all browsers, mainly IE though and on multiple PCs/networks. I will get the head tag info ASAP and post it here.

And this happens occasionally. Most of the times, the site runs just fine.

Unfortunately, cant post the site URLs here, as requested by client.

The Head Tag content is as follows

```
    <head id="ctl00_Head"><title>
    Test Site
</title><meta name="author" content="test" /><meta name="revisit-after" content="1 day" /><meta name="robots" content="index, follow " /><meta name="Copyright" content="Copyright" /><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Include/site.css" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cachedcommons.org/cache/cufon/1.0.9/javascripts/cufon-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/jquery.cycle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/Kaufmann_Std_italic_700.font.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/swfforcesize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/swfaddress.js?html=false&history=1&tracker=pageTracker._trackPageview&strict=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/flash_resize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/flashVersion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Include/run.js"></script>

    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Include/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Include/ie6.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.uniquewebsites.com.au/clientservices/MobileRedirect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("testsite1") >= 0)
        redirectMobileBrowsers("mobile.testsite1.com.au");

    if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("testsite2") >= 0)
        redirectMobileBrowsers("mobile.testsite2.com.au");
    </script>
</head>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you let us know the URL, and whether it's happening on more then one browser, more then on PC, more then one network, etc. If you have access to the source code, posting the `<head>` tags would help as well

Comment: Added this info to the question! Thanks Luke!!

Comment: I don't see the information addded yet...

Comment: Leave us the link here as a comment.

Comment: @Somya Unfortunately, without the link it's going to be a lot more difficult for us to help you troubleshoot

Comment: I have added the Head Tag content.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the JavaScript source files, or the actual URL, I am going to guess that it has to do with the last bit of JavaScript, mainly this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.uniquewebsites.com.au/clientservices/MobileRedirect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("testsite1") >= 0)
   redirectMobileBrowsers("mobile.testsite1.com.au");

if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("testsite2") >= 0)
    redirectMobileBrowsers("mobile.testsite2.com.au");
</script>
```

I would try commenting those two script blocks out, and see if it keeps doing that. Again without the URL or the source code of those JavaScript scripts, this is the best we can offer.